# Cómo puedo Igualar dos variables por una condicional en java

Tags: java, bucle-for

Miren, lo que quiero lograr es que **D iguale el valor de A**, de ejemplo estoy usando que **A es 6 y D es 2**, entonces el for tiene que aumentar el valor de D hasta que pueda igualar a A, traté de usar `D*=i;` pero claro, de esta manera no funciona, el resultado se almacena en D. Quiero aclarar que D debe igualar a A por medio de una multiplicación, en el ejemplo que he dado de D = 2, A = 6, pues tendría que multiplicarse x3. Este es el código que he usado.

```
package ecuacioneslineales;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class EcuacionesLineales {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int A, D;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Dame tu primer valor de X");
        A = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Dame tu segundo valor de X");
        D = in.nextInt();
        
        for (int i = 1; D == A; i++) {
             D*=i;           
        }
        System.out.println("El valor de A es " + A + " El valor de D es " + D);
    }

}
```

**Esto es lo que se imprime: "El valor de A es 6 El valor de D es 2"**
Esto es lo que quiero que se imprima: **"El valor de A es 6 El valor de D es 6"**

Comment: Por qué si quieres igualarla... estás multiplicándola?? Lo lógico sería que sumases 1 cada paso, no que multiplicases por `i`! `D*=i` es igual a `D = D * i`,  lo que quieres usar es `D+=i`! Eso sumará i en cada paso. De todas maneras... dado que vas a ir cambiando el valor de `i`, realmente tal cual lo planteas lo lógico sería sumar `1` a cada paso, y no `1`, luego `2`, luego `3`... Así que técnicamente, tendrías que usar `D+=1`

Comment: Sí, lo lógico sería sumarlo de uno en uno, PERO, necesito que sea multiplicado, porque lo que estoy haciendo es un sistema de ecuaciones, entonces, digamos que D se multiplicó x 3 para alcanzar a A, pues no solo D se multiplicará, sino también las variables E y F (no lo puse en el código de demostración de arriba). Es obligatorio que se encuentre por medio de una multiplicación, sí o sí.

Comment: ¿Multiplicación solo de enteros supongo por el tipo de datos? ¿Que esperas hacer en el caso en el que no sea posible una igualación? Porque obviamente si `A = 5` y `D = 2` no hay manera en que se pueda lograr con enteros.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez tengo unas líneas de código que lo que hacen es que si A es impar se multiplicará x2, en el caso que A = 5 y D = 2, pues se aplica esta línea de código:
        if (A % 2 != 0) {
            A*=2;
            B*=2;
            C*=2;
        }
y ahora A al valer 10, D sí podría alcanzarlo

Answer (score 0):

El valor de `i` dentro del for tendría que tener el valor correspondiente al segundo valor de `x` ,y la condicional del bucle for  debe ser que `i` sea menor al primer valor de `x`

ejemplo si `D` es `2` i tomara ese valor y aumentara de 1 en 1 hasta que sea menor a 6 ejecutándose 4 veces al ser menor que 6... D+1+1+1+1=6

```
for (int i = D; i<A; i++) {
            D++;         
        }
```

Con la aclaración que hiciste por que usar un ciclo for? cuando puedes aplicar una linea de código  como reemplazo

```
D=D*(A/D);
```

Comment: tu código sería bastante efectivo en el escenario que planteas, sé que esto es error mío, me olvidé aclarar que D debe igualar a A multiplicándose, en el ejemplo de D = 2, A = 6; tendría que multiplicarse x3, por ejemplo, por eso hice lo que hice. No sé si podrás ayudarme ahora que sabes que es necesario que se igualen sí o sí por una multiplicación

Comment: @AndréDv edite la respuesta

Comment: ¿`D=D*A(/D)` no es lo mismo que `D = A`? De cualquier forma no es tu culpa. El problema no tiene ni pies ni cabeza. No tiene sentido un ciclo `for `para encontrar `i = A/D`

Comment: en concreto  si, en operación si lo que  quiere es incluir una multiplicación, me parece una opción viable, puesto que no hay cabida en usar un bucle xD!

Answer (score -2):

```
package ecuacioneslineales;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class EcuacionesLineales {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int A, D;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Dame tu primer valor de X");
        A = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Dame tu segundo valor de X");
        D = in.nextInt()
        int c = 0;
        for( int i = 1 ; D * i != A; i++) {
            c = D * i;            
        }
        D = c;
        System.out.println("El valor de A es " + A + " El valor de D es " + D);
    }
}
```

La versión anterior cumple con lo que se pide, el bucle  for itera hasta mientras que "D" por "i", no sea igual a "A", mientras itera, va multiplicando "D" por "i" y carga el resultado en "c", cuando se incumple la condición del for, sale del bucle, a "D" se le carga el valor de "c", y se imprime el resultado.

```
int c = 0;
int i = 1;
for( ; D * i != A; i++ ) {
    c = D * i;            
}
D = c;
System.out.println( "El valor de A, que es " + A + ", se obtiene multiplicando el valor de D, que es " + D + " por " + i );
```

En esta segunda versión, saco la declaración de "i" del for, para poder modificar lo que se imprime, y que tenga un poco más de sentido.

```
for ( int i = 1; ; i++) {
    if( D * i == A ) {
        System.out.println( "El valor de A, que es " + A + ", se obtiene multiplicando el valor de D, que es " + D + " por " + i );
        break;
    }  
    if( D * i > A ) {
        System.out.println( "A es " + A + ", y no es divisible por D, que es " + D );
        break;
    }     
}
```

Por último, una versión del mismo que maneja valores de entrada incorrectos, el primer bucle "if", verifica si "D" por "i", es igual a "A", si lo es, imprime el resultado y por medio de la instrucción "break", nos saca de "for" (nótese que el en el "for", la condición esta en blanco, por lo que, de no usar el "break", tendriamos un bucle infinito), si la condición del primer "if" no es verdadera, se evalua el segundo, si "D * i" es mayor que "A", e imprime el mensaje apropiado.